# pandas groupby flag record and apply back to original dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Below is a dataframe that contains groups and a column called input. Id like to create a second column which would flags the first occurrence of the column input by group, and for the rest of the records within group sets it to 0. Below is an example:

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c'], 
                            'input': [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]})

   group  input
0      a      0
1      a      1
2      a      1
3      b      0
4      b      0
5      c      0
6      c      0
7      c      0
8      c      0
9      c      1
10     c      1
11     c      1
12     c      1

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c'], 
                            'input': [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],  
                            'desired_input': [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]})

   group  input  desired_input
0      a      0              0
1      a      1              1
2      a      1              0
3      b      0              0
4      b      0              0
5      c      0              0
6      c      0              0
7      c      0              0
8      c      0              0
9      c      1              1
10     c      1              0
11     c      1              0
12     c      1              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try drop_duplicates:

```py
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
     'input': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

df['flag'] = df[df['input'].eq(1)] \
    .drop_duplicates(['group'], keep='first')['input']
df['flag'] = df['flag'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   group  input  flag
0      a      0     0
1      a      1     1
2      a      1     0
3      b      1     1
4      b      1     0
5      c      0     0
6      c      0     0
7      c      0     0
8      c      0     0
9      c      1     1
10     c      1     0
11     c      1     0
12     c      1     0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails when there are consecutive 1's between groups

Comment: Unfortunately, still same result, it fails when there are consectuve 1's between groups. See example DF: original_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c'], 
                            'input': [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]})

Comment: Okay. Different approach. I didn't understand what you meant by consecutive 1s between groups the first time. Please see the edit.